# dynamic_reconfigure is not working with Diamondback

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to put dynamic_reconfigure package to my node.

But when I create a new node with the following tutorial, http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode , It doesn't publish any topic.

For the example on the dynamic_reconfigure package(testserver) also doesn't work. It just stops then I should press "Ctrl+" to quit the process.

Is there anyone who encounter this problem?

Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9875/dynamic_reconfigure-is-not-working-with-diamondback..../) by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 177 on 2011-05-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works the different machine which has exact same version of ROS and Linux.

ROS is diamond back, version 1.4.6
Linux is Ubuntu 10.04, Kernel version 2.6.35-28

Is there anyone who knows about this problem?

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) with karma: 177 on 2011-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-05-03**:
PS it's better to update your question than to answer it, unless you consider it closed.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-05-03**:
Can you look a little closer at the differences between the two machines?  There must be something.